# Catch response in Windows batch file

Tags: git, batch-file

I am making a small batch file to pull from git. I use the following:

```
call git pull origin master
```

But would like the rest of the batch file to stop running when the response of the command is `Already up-to-date.`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe it to `findstr` then check the error level

```
git pull | findstr /C:"Already up-to-date"

IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO:EOF

echo Continuing ....
```

To explain the relationship of `findstr` and `errorlevel` http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html says:

```
FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows:

0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).
2 Wrong syntax 
An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream.
```

Comment: Added text to explain how this works